# SVN Checkout error in Jenkns

Tags: maven, svn, jenkins

I am trying to check out code from SVN, it doesn't work for first time. But in second attempt, same project works fine. Please guide. The error is as follows:

```
Started by user anonymous
Building remotely on ARA (Demo) in workspace C:\Workspace-Jenkins\workspace\SVN-Maven-demo
Switching from file:///C:/SVN_Repo/Developer Directory to file:///C:/SVN_Repo/Developer%20Directory
Switching to file:///C:/SVN_Repo/Developer Directory at revision '2015-06-19T18:07:31.577 +0530'
U         WebContent\home.jsp
At revision 80
hudson.util.IOException2: revision check failed on file:///C:/SVN_Repo/Developer Directory
    at hudson.scm.SubversionChangeLogBuilder.buildModule(SubversionChangeLogBuilder.java:196)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionChangeLogBuilder.run(SubversionChangeLogBuilder.java:123)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.calcChangeLog(SubversionSCM.java:725)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.checkout(SubversionSCM.java:860)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:484)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1265)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:622)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:528)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1759)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:89)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:240)
Caused by: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E180001: Unable to open an ra_local session to URL
svn: E180001: Unable to open repository 'file:///C:/SVN_Repo/Developer%20Directory'
svn: E180001: Unable to open repository 'file:///C:/SVN_Repo/Developer%20Directory'
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:64)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:51)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.fs.FSRepository.openRepository(FSRepository.java:796)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.fs.FSRepository.getLatestRevision(FSRepository.java:121)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgRepositoryAccess.getRevisionNumber(SvnNgRepositoryAccess.java:118)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.SvnRepositoryAccess.getLocations(SvnRepositoryAccess.java:184)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgRepositoryAccess.createRepositoryFor(SvnNgRepositoryAccess.java:45)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.remote.SvnRemoteLog.run(SvnRemoteLog.java:160)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.remote.SvnRemoteLog.run(SvnRemoteLog.java:35)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.SvnOperationRunner.run(SvnOperationRunner.java:21)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperationFactory.run(SvnOperationFactory.java:1259)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperation.run(SvnOperation.java:294)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNLogClient.doLog(SVNLogClient.java:968)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNLogClient.doLog(SVNLogClient.java:873)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionChangeLogBuilder.buildModule(SubversionChangeLogBuilder.java:184)
    ... 12 more
```

Comment: Can you try to remove the space in your folder name? (Developer_Directory instead of Developer Directory)

Comment: Hi Bruno. It didn't work.

Comment: Hi :) If you go into the directory (on the build machine), are you able to update your SVN folder? (cmd --> svn up)

Comment: Yes. I can update it.

Comment: Could you update question and add new error message after remove spaces in repository path?

Comment: By any chance, do you have a `svn:externals` property on one of your directories? I've seen that *revision check failed on* when there's an `svn:external`. Also ***NEVER EVER USE  file:\\ for checkouts!***. Use `svn://` or `http://`. You can run `svnserve` as a Windows Service. Do that.

Answer (score 0):

Accurately compare your **time** and **timezones** between the Jenkins server and the SVN server. They should be pretty close in-sync (use some LDAP or NTP sync).